# python searching for string starting with letter

Tags: python, mysql

```
data = cursor.fetchone ( )
while data is not None:
    data = str(data)
    print(data)
    data.split(",")
    for index in data:
        if index.startswith("K"):
            print(index, end=';')
    data = cursor.fetchone()
```

Here is the relevant part of my code. The data is retrieved from a mysql server, and is a long string of text separated by commas. I can split the string with the commas fine, however, I then need to search for 4 letter strings. I know they start with K, but when I run the program it only prints the K. How do I get it to print the whole string.
Sample Data:
"N54,W130,KRET,KMPI,COFFEE"
Expected output:
"N54,W130,KRET,KMPI,COFFEE"
"KRET;KMPI;"

Comment: Amend your question to include some example data and expected output on that data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line `data.split(",")` does nothing because you need to assign that value. You also said you want to only print the K? If so you only want to print the first character of the string so `d[0]`

```
data = cursor.fetchone ( )
while data is not None:
    data = str(data)
    print(data)
    data = data.split(",")
    for d in data:
        if d.startswith("K"):
             print(d, end=';')
    data = cursor.fetchone()
```

EDIT: Based on your edit it seems you want to entire string to be printed so I updated it for that

Comment: your first tip worked, and my issue before was that it was only printing the first letter, but I wanted all four. Splitting it like this fixed the issue, though

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for 4 letters string starting with "K", What about using regular expressions?

```
import re

regex = r"K[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}"

test_str="N54,W130,KRET,KMPI,COFFEE"

matches = re.finditer(regex,test_str)

output=""
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    output+=match.group()+";"

print(output)
```

The output is: KRET;KMPI;